# Convert SQL command to Linq Lambda function?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

```
SELECT     
    dbo.Projects.TaskMaster, dbo.Projects.Location, dbo.Photos.Photo
FROM
    dbo.Photos 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Projects ON dbo.Photos.ProjectID = dbo.Projects.ProjectID
WHERE
    (dbo.Projects.IsTopProject = 1)
```

I need to implement this SQL command using Linq Lambda .

Comment: How's your object model?

Comment: I using the database first. and fetch data by : `ProjectRepository blProject = new ProjectRepository();
            IEnumerable<Project> projects = blProject.Select().Where(x => x.IsTopProject == true).ToList();

            PhotoRepository blPhoto = new PhotoRepository();
            IEnumerable<Photo> photos = blPhoto.Select();`

Comment: @Aram please [edit] any additional information directly into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = dbo.Projects
    // you only want the top projects:
    .Where(project => project.IsTopProject == 1)

    .Join(dbo.Photos              // join the remaining Projects with Photos
    project => project.ProjectId, // from every project take the ProjectId,
    photo => photo.ProjectId,     // from every photo take the ProjectId,
    (project, photo) => new       // when they match make one new object
    {                             // containing the following properties:
         TaskMaster = project.TaskMaster,
         Location = project.Location,
         Photo = project.Photo,
    });
```

Quite often people are interested in "Top projects with their Photos", or "Schools with their Students" or "Customers with their Orders". In such cases a GroupJoin might be more interesting.

The normal inner join will give you the following sequence:

```
Project  Photo
   A       3
   A       4
   B       2
   A       6
   C       1
   B       5
```

The GroupJoin will result in this:

- Project A with photos 3, 4, 6
- Project B with photos 2, 5
- Project C with photo 1
- Project D has no photos yet.

Apart from that this feels more natural, the advantage is, that if you have a Project with 1000 Photos, you'll only transfer the Project properties once, instead of a 1000 times.

To do this, consider the following statement:

```
var result = dbo.Projects.Where(project => project.IsTopProject == 1)
    .GroupJoin(dbo.Photos                // GroupJoin the remaining Projects with Photos
    project => project.ProjectId,        // from every project take the ProjectId,
    photo => photo.ProjectId,            // from every photo take the ProjectId,
    (project, photosOfThisProject => new // from every project with all its matching
    {                                    // photos, make one new object
         TaskMaster = project.TaskMaster,
         Location = project.Location,

         Photos = photosOfThisProject.ToList(),

         // or if you only need some Photo properties:
         ProjectId = project.ProjectId,
         Photos = photosOfThisProject.Select( photo => new
         {
              // select the Photo properties that you plan to use
              Id = photo.Id,
              ...

              // not needed: you know the value:
              // ProjectId = photo.ProjectId,
         })
         .ToList()
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
from photo in dbContext.Photos
join project in dbContext.Projects
on photo.ProjectID equals project.ProjectID
where project.IsTopProject == 1
select new { 
   photo.Photo, 
   project.TaskMaster,
   project.Location
};
```

If you really want to use lambdas, give this a shot:

```
dbContent.Photos
   .Join(dbContext.Projects.Where(x => x.Project.IsTopProject == 1), 
         photo => photo.ProjectID,
         project => project.ProjectID,
         (photo, project) => new { 
            photo.Photo, 
            project.TaskMaster,
            project.Location 
         });
```

Comment: Thanks, But i need Lambda. usable the Join method in c#

Comment: @Aram personally, I find query expressions a lot easier to read. Lambdas expressions can get super messy, especially with multiple Joins. But feel free to use whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = database.Photos   
   .Join(database.Projects, 
      photos => photos.ProjectID,      
      project => project.ProjectID,   
      (photos, project) => new {Photos = photos, Projects = project}) 
   .Where(photosAndproject => photosAndproject.Projects.IsTopProject = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            var result = await yourContext.Projects.Where(proj => proj.IsTopProject == true)
                   .Join(yourContext.Photos,
                         proj => proj.ProjectId,
                         photo => photo.ProjectID,
                         (proj,
                          photo) => new resultType
                                    {
                                        proj.TaskMaster,
                                        proj.Location,
                                        photo.Photo
                                    }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Thanks, the resultType is `Context.Projects` but the `photo.Photo` get error. why?

Comment: resultType need to be a anonymous type or same DTO, this is just projection of you data. Type Projects do not have Photo property.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
SELECT     dbo.Projects.TaskMaster, dbo.Projects.Location, dbo.Photos.Photo
FROM         dbo.Photos INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Projects ON dbo.Photos.ProjectID = dbo.Projects.ProjectID
WHERE     (dbo.Projects.IsTopProject = 1)
```

should be something like

```
var q = db.Photos()
          .Where( p => Projects.IsTopProject )
          .Select( p => new 
              {
               p.Project.TaskMaster, 
               p.Project.Location, 
               p.Photo
              });
```

In EF, you should use [Navigation Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/navigation-property) instead of Join().